# How to pass a raw string and enum to a parameter packed function

Tags: c++, templates

While trying to code a small renderer I would like my struc `MeshComponent` to hold a `std::vector<Texture>` where Texture is a Class with multiple constructors. Furthermore, I want the ownership of `Textures` to be held by my vector.

### My initial attempt:

Thus in `MeshComponent` I have to following method to insert a Texture into my vector using template packing (inspired by the `emplace_back` method of `std::vector`):

```cpp
template<typename... TextArgs>
MeshComponent *MeshComponent::addTexture(const TextArgs&&... texArgs) {
    textures.emplace_back(std::forward<TextArgs>(texArgs)...);
    return this;
}
```

And I try using it in the following way:

```cpp
mesh = OGLR::MeshComponent::loadFromObjFile("path_to.obj")
        ->addShader("path_to_shader.vert.glsl", "path_to_shader.frag.glsl")
        ->addTexture("path_to_texture.png", OGLR::Texture::Type::X4B);
```

Where `OGLR::Texture::Type::X4B` is a enum indicating the type of texture.

### My error:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'const char (&&)[31]' to lvalue of type 'const char [31]'
   15 |             ->addTexture("path_to_texture.png", OGLR::Texture::Type::X4B);
```

### My attempts to solve this:

- Changing the signature to:

  ```cpp
  MeshComponent *MeshComponent::addTexture(const TextArgs&... texArgs)
  ```

  Which produced:

  ```
    undefined reference to `OGLR::MeshComponent* OGLR::MeshComponent::addTexture<char [31], OGLR::Texture::Type>(char const (&) [31], OGLR::Texture::Type const&)'
  ```
- With the original signature:
  Storing `"path_to_texture.png"` into a `std::string` variable before calling addTexture with it's reference but then I got (I would also REALY like not to have to do that):

  ```
  undefined reference to `OGLR::MeshComponent* OGLR::MeshComponent::addTexture<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, OGLR::Texture::Type>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* const&&, OGLR::Texture::Type const&&)'
  ```

So... yeah I'm a bit lost and would realy love to understand what I messed up and if there is a neat way to do this. So any ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: `const TextArgs&&... texArgs` -> `TextArgs&&... texArgs`. But my advice would simply be not to bother, just do `addTexture(Texture tex)`, `textures.push_back(std::move(text));`. Save the clever templates for when you're writing a custom container or the like, and really need it to be optimal.